# iis7 logging performance in ASP.NET application web forms

Tags: performance, iis-7

iis7 logging performance

Is it possible to Log loading time for my pages in ASP.NET application

Something like this

http://localhost:80/Platina/EKH/ = 26ms

Answer (score 0):

A simple option, if you have IIS logging switched on for the website, you could look at the time-taken field in the resulting log files. The time is measured in milliseconds, e.g time-taken value of 1000 is one second.

'The time-taken field measures the length of time that it takes for a request to be processed'

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/944884

This may also be helpful :
https://rothmanshore.com/2011/04/22/performance-yes-time-taken-in-iis-includes-network-time/